# How to parse JsonArray values in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I would like to parse all name and id attribute from the following JSon Array:
[JSon link](http://myjson.com/3p3hk)

I tried with the following code but not working. I get

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":0,"name":"Alsópetény"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Exception

My code :

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonList);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id= jsonobject.getString("id");
                    String name= jsonobject.getString("name");

                    System.out.print("ID:\n"+id+"");
                    System.out.print("NAME:\n"+name+"");
                }
```

Comment: I ran your code with `jsonList = "[{\"id\":0,\"name\":\"Alsópetény\"}]"` and no error was produced...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yours (as I can see from the link you've posted) is a single JSON message {...} wich contains many nodes ("A","B", "E", "F"... and so on). Every node is a JSON Array wich contains some JSON Objects.

You must Get first the JSON Objects: "A", "B",... this way:

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //the result of HTTP call
JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray ja = JO.getJSONArray("A");
JSONArray jb = JO.getJSONArray("B");
...
```

Then you must access to the JsonArray elements:

```
for(int i=0; i< ja.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = jo.getString("id");
    String name = jo.getString("name");

    System.out.println("id: " + id + "");
    System.out.println("name: " + name + "");
}
```